# Did I ruin my lemon tree?

Tags: trees, lemons

[image]

Hey guys I just bought a house in so cal. The backyard lemon tree was overgrown really bad. Had lots and lots of intertwined dead branches. I read online to cut the diseased branches off but I probably over did it. Can my tree be saved ?[image]

Comment: Where's the graft point?

Comment: Sorry didn’t realize how bad my first picture was. I uploaded a second picture.

Comment: Just wait till next spring and see if anything happens. If not, it's firewood. If it does produce some buds and new growth, *that* is the time to decide whether it's worth trying to "save" it, and if so what to do. Note, depending on where it is situated, you might need to protect it from people who don't actually realize it's supposed to be a tree in its current state!

Comment: Agreed, you are just going to have to wait and find out later.

Comment: Do I continue watering it ?